# CartThrob - Changing Order - Re-process?

Tags: cartthrob

I am pretty sure I know the answer to my question but wanted a second opinion.

A client asked 'If we change/add to an order already entered, will these changes be re-process through the payment gateway'. I am 99% sure no, but I thought I should check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, orders need to be *submitted* to the payment gateway and changing an order in the back-end wont make the submission.

Cartthrob will allow you to do this as orders are just stored as a regular channel entry but be very careful because you don't want your orders getting out of sync with the actual payments that were made.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was assuming. But with something as important as payment processing, I wanted to be 100% sure.